# Setting up Pivot Table with Financial Years

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am wanting to setup a pivot table that has data for 2 years (for example: 2019 and 2020). I want the rows to be for example, sales & COGS. The columns to be monthly and at the end of every 3 months there would a columns for quarterly totals. And the column after that would be quarter-over-quarter for comparison. See uploaded picture. How can I setup the pivot table to show the structure below??

[image]

The current setup that I have looks like this. That is not the final result I am looking for.
[image]

Here is a sample of raw data:

```
| Date       | $ Amount | City    | State | Category | Quarter | Year |
|------------|----------|---------|-------|----------|---------|------|
| 12/10/2019 | 200      | Houston | TX    | Sales    | 4       | 2019 |
| 12/2/2019  | 120      | Houston | TX    | CoGS     | 4       | 2019 |
| 12/10/2019 | 150      | LA      | CA    | Sales    | 4       | 2019 |
| 12/2/2019  | 100      | LA      | CA    | CoGS     | 4       | 2019 |
| 1/10/2020  | 20       | Houston | TX    | Sales    | 1       | 2020 |
| 1/2/2020   | 10       | Houston | TX    | CoGS     | 1       | 2020 |
| 1/10/2020  | 30       | LA      | CA    | Sales    | 1       | 2020 |
| 1/2/2020   | 15       | LA      | CA    | CoGS     | 1       | 2020 |
| 2/10/2020  | 30       | Houston | TX    | Sales    | 1       | 2020 |
| 2/2/2020   | 20       | Houston | TX    | CoGS     | 1       | 2020 |
| 2/10/2020  | 100      | LA      | CA    | Sales    | 1       | 2020 |
| 2/2/2020   | 50       | LA      | CA    | CoGS     | 1       | 2020 |
| 3/10/2020  | 75       | Houston | TX    | Sales    | 1       | 2020 |
| 3/2/2020   | 40       | Houston | TX    | CoGS     | 1       | 2020 |
| 3/10/2020  | 50       | LA      | CA    | Sales    | 1       | 2020 |
| 3/2/2020   | 35       | LA      | CA    | CoGS     | 1       | 2020 |
| 4/10/2020  | 200      | Houston | TX    | Sales    | 2       | 2020 |
| 4/2/2020   | 120      | Houston | TX    | CoGS     | 2       | 2020 |
| 4/10/2020  | 60       | LA      | CA    | Sales    | 2       | 2020 |
| 4/2/2020   | 45       | LA      | CA    | CoGS     | 2       | 2020 |
```

And here is the resultant pivot table (not the end result I am looking for).
[image]

Comment: It may be that Power Query or VBA is a better tool with which to set this up. What does your source data look like?  *A text example that can be copy/pasted would be ideal.*

Comment: The data format is a column with date, city, state, dollar amount, and a column that defines what category the $ amount is for. There is about 10 different categories. I was using pivot tables as I still want to have slicers for filtering areas and type of expenses. I think VBA will diminsh that effort. What do you mean by a text example?

Comment: Text is text and not a picture. Example means a representative sample of your data. That way, the text can be copy/pasted into a worksheet instead of trying to reproduce it from guesswork. Do not include any confidential information. Consider using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to format the text.

Comment: I have pasted into the main question - but it does not look formatted the same way I copied it from Markdown Tables. Also, if the data needs restructuring to achieve the final result, that is doable on my end.

Comment: After you paste it in, you need to format it as code.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the structure below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That is my current setup and I have edited my question to show that output. That is not what I am looking for.